# jQuery move divs according to mouse position

Tags: jquery, html, position, mouse

I got a little Problem with jQuery, maybe you guys can help me. Here's the HTML Markup in jfiddle for better understanding:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M4SwL/12/)

I'd like to have the div called #move_me to move either to the right or to the left side within the `#content_wrapper` according to the mouse position inside `#content_wrapper`.

Basically what I want is: if I move my cursor inside the `#content_wrapper` div to the right then the `#move_me` div should move to the left to see content2 div, when I move to the left the #move_me div should move to the right to see content1 div..

I tried to get it to work with mousemove and pageXoffset but I didn't get it to work.

something like this:

```
$('#content_wrapper').mousemove(function(e){
var x = e.pageX - this.parentoffsetLeft;
$('#move_me').css({'left': x}); 
});
```

HERE IS AN IMAGE EXPLAINING MORE PRECISELY:

[Illustration http://www.22labs.com/moveme.jpg](http://www.22labs.com/moveme.jpg)

Answer (score 7):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/M4SwL/17/)

Try this

I guess this is what you need, Add `position:relative;` to your `move_me`

### code

```
$('#content_wrapper').mousemove(function (e) {

    $('#move_me').animate({
        'left': -e.pageX + 15 + 'px'
    }, 0);

});
```

Hope this helps, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I partly wrote a solution. Hope this is what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/NukSy/4/

```
$('div#content1').mousemove(function(p) {     
    $("div#content1").css('left', p.pageX + moveLeft);
    $("div#content2").animate({left: "0px"}, 500);
  });
```

Regards :))

Comment: thanks man, but unfortunately thats not exactly what i tried to achieve :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).mousemove(function(event){
$("div").attr("style","padding-left:"+event.pageX+"px; padding-top:"+event.pageY+"px");
});
});
</script>

<div style="">
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="username" />
<input type="password" placeholder="password" />
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```