# How to scroll a gallery acording to the position of the mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I would like to achieve something like the homepage of this website: http://www.k2.pl/.

Basically the gallery moves according to the position of the mouse. I wonder if there are libraries that accomplish that. If not, how could I achieve that effect using JavaScript?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Bad idea. Some people don't even have a mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the mouse position via jquery as follows

```
$().mousemove(function(e){
// e.pageX - gives you X position
// e.pageY - gives you Y position
});
```

You could then make all the divs absolute and in your javascript perform a x translation of the div based on the position. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_transform.asp. Note that the example page you showed also sizes the divs so you would probably need to check the position to a relative ratio of the window.width(). I searched around a little and found the following post and fiddle that might get you started:  [jQuery move divs according to mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338608/jquery-move-divs-according-to-mouse-position) , http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/M4SwL/17/